# Get siblings from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have setup an custom post type with the structure below:

- Main post

  - Children post

    - Sibling post

I have two main posts called "Vrouwen" en "Mannen"
When i visit one of these main posts i would like to only display the siblings.

Im stuck in achieving this.

But then the "children" are also displayed.
I need to go one level deeper somehow.

All help is appreciated!

I tried the code below.

```
$mysibling        = $post->post_parent;
$mychild          = $post->ID;
$mychildmysibling = array( $mychild, $mysibling );

$args = array(
    'post_parent'    => $mychildmysibling,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'       => 'collectie'
);

$parent = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();
```

But then the "children" are also displayed. I need to go one level deeper somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `post_parent` expects a number but you set an array. Secondly, you basically need to make it work only for the main pages? So query should look like this:

```
// find children for the main post
$children = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID));

// check if the post has any children
if ( ! empty($children) ) {
   // get all posts where the parent is set as children to main post
   $args = array(
        'post_parent__in' => array_keys($children),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'collectie'
    );

   $siblings = new WP_Query( $args );

   if ( $siblings->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $siblings->have_posts() ) {
           $siblings->the_post();

           echo get_the_title();
       }
   }

   wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Im getting closer, but the children are also displayed.

Comment: I only need to get the siblings.

Comment: Nevermind! I made a mistake! It WORKSSS! Thank you very much